# Anyone know a name for this measuring tool?

Tags: tools, measuring, measurement

I've been looking at height gauges and they don't quite fit what I need.  I'm trying to measure a ceiling not an object.

I've seen some old fashioned height gauges that seem to do what I'm looking for but I'm hoping I just don't know the name or something.

I have one of those plastic gauges showing up but it doesn't inspire a lot of confidence.  If you can point me in a direction I'm much obliged.

Comment: tape measure works well for measuring the height of a ceiling

Comment: Not literally a ceiling above my head

Comment: I need something like a micrometer

Comment: I was looking at an inside diameter micrometer but im not sure if it will stand and measure a flat ceiling

Comment: 'Those plastic gauges' makes me think of [Vernier Calipers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers), which are available in both plastic and metal versions. But I think there might be a language barrier here as I can't think of any other definition of ceiling apart from a literal one.

Comment: Take a deep breath, please, @user120474. Not sure what's got you quite so riled up, but people are trying to help. English certainly isn't the only language in the world, but it's _the_ language here at SE, if it's not your native tongue, that's perfectly fine and you speak it better than I speak your language - guaranteed. However, we're not getting what you're asking. The English definition of [ceiling](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ceiling), especially on a home improvement site is that flat thing above your head. If you mean something else please include a pic of it.

Comment: Sorry to see it's closed, but pretty sure you're looking for a telescoping measuring pole.

Comment: Please do come back to [edit] your question to clarify it. I'm really curious about what you're trying to measure and what device you're trying to use to do so. Once we've got some more details, I'm sure the question will be reopened and you'll get a very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what type of ceiling you are measuring, but the old fashioned way I know to do it accurately are using "tick sticks", 2 pieces of wood that are shorter than the length you need but when combined together, they are long enough to measure the area. Mark the stick accordingly or clamp them together to maintain the length that the area provided.